# Алгоритм для разбиения текста на части

Tags: алгоритм, текст

Я ищу алгоритм для разбиения текста на части. В чем суть, к примеру у нас имеется текст размером в `100_000` символов, его надо разбить на части по `7000` символов, при этом предложение должно остаться целым, без обрезки, т.е. для разбиения нужно найти символ окончания строки, точку, пробел или красную строку, даже если мы не уместимся в условные `7000` тысяч, предложение должно остаться целым.

Я понимаю, что это можно реализовать самому, но может я упускаю из вида уже имеющейся алгоритм, который будет работать быстро и без ошибок при его реализации, если кто-то знает о таком, буду благодарен.

Comment: Хм, делить какую-нибудь «библиотеку им. Ленина» по точкам нетривиально

Comment: омг, это случайно не лаба со второго курса в УлГТУ? не уверен что для такой простой и специфичный задачи есть "готовый" алгоритм. решение банальное как тапок, прешся в 7000 элемент и ищеш первый нужный разделитель. Если его так и нет вплоть до 0 идёшь в сторону увеличения ни чего тут не придумать. Если я прав на счёт первого вопроса то основная сложность это правильно буферизвать данные с диска в памяти.

Comment: @Arenoros, нет, это не лаба

Comment: @Arenoros, про то, что можно переться в 7000 символов мне и самому понятно, вопрос был в другом, есть ли что-то готовое, чтобы не писать велосипеды. Думать и додумывать ничего не надо, вопрос вполне конкретный.

Comment: @Arenoros откуда у вас уверенность, у автора вопроса гарантированно не будет текстов с «библиотеками им. Ленина» или «улицами ак. Константинова»?